# Restoring an older C# project into newer versions of Visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to get this old C# client server based live chat application running in SQL Server 2017 Management Studio, and SQL Server 2008 (it's the only version the backup would restore in), but I am getting some errors.

I googled them and tried solving them myself but the solutions offered don't seem to be working, these are the ones from stackoverflow but for me they didn't work.

Here is what I've done so far:

The project is made in 2005-2008 something so I installed SQL Server 2008 and restored the database from the backup successfully. I created the new database as said in the thingstofollow.txt (readme.txt) and created a new one later.

The problem is in SQL Server Management Studio; there is no option to enter login ID on startup like it says in instruction, if I enter sysname (actual sysname- not sysname literally) / localhost it fails to connect so I just connected with SQL Server Express something that is in drop down, then created a new database giving it custome name and restored the .bak file in it like it says.

Then I opened Visual Studio and opened the code folder and edited the details in `web.congfig` file as said, SQL Server 2008 did as for a password at time of installation so I entered `12345` (same as I gave then) but I noticed that it has `user id=sa`, when I never entered id at the time of whole restoring part as said in above, so the errors I am getting are:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line
>   Error the file '/Admin/Update/MasterPage.master' does not exist.
>   D:\cl-se-bas\4\Code-LiveMeeting\Code-LiveMeeting\Admin\Update\frmUpdateCountry.aspx 1

and

> Severity Code Description Project File Line
>   Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Country' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Code-LiveMeeting D:\cl-se-bas\4\Code-LiveMeeting\Code-LiveMeeting\Admin\Update\frmUpdateCountry.aspx.cs 14

and

> Severity Code Description Project File Line
>   Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IncomeBL' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Code-LiveMeeting D:\cl-se-bas\4\Code-LiveMeeting\Code-LiveMeeting\Admin\Update\frmUpdateIncome.aspx.cs 14

And there are some warnings about:

Validation(HTML5) align not being valid attribute of  HTML5

**Solutions I tried:**

I looked online and someone said change ~ to a . in ./Admin/masterasdpageetc.. to resolve it but it only gives me a code/somethingsomethkg/Admin doesn't exist error instead

Then there is changing build type under properties to .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 etc since due to that one project can't look into other's classes and namespaces but I only have one project,

Ok so changing the build type to 2.0 fixed the HTML5 error (as expected) but the rest are still there

> Severity Code Description Project File Line
>   Warning File '~/Admin/Update/MasterPage.master' was not found. Code-LiveMeeting D:\cl-se-bas\4\Code-LiveMeeting\Code-LiveMeeting\Admin\Update\frmUpdateIncome.aspx 1

and

> Severity Code Description Project File Line
>   Warning Could not find 'ContentPlaceHolder1' in the current master page or pages. Code-LiveMeeting D:\cl-se-bas\4\Code-LiveMeeting\Code-LiveMeeting\Admin\Update\frmUpdateIncome.aspx 2

MS discontinued all earlier versions of visual studio earlier to 2010.

Screenshot of whole instruction file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4oSM.jpg

**Edit:** I updated the images, the MasterPage.master file does exist as it is in solution explorer.

Comment: Exclude all folders/fies first. Do the Build. If successfull then include 1 master page. If successfull than proceed step by step.

Comment: Bit confusing but the default install of sqlserver the sysadmin is the windows user that installed. you can add an sa user, but when you do that you are being authorised in whats called mixed mode as sql user not a windows user. So may be just adding the sa user and allowing mixed mode will do it.

Comment: Pasting the whole path of MasterPage from properties seem to have gotten rid of "file doesn't exist" errors, but then it gives a "path_here" is a physical path but expected a virtual path error. Other Type or namespace could not be found errors still persists though. And HTML5 error came back.

Comment: VS2008 came with Net 3.0 (around year 2007)  and then within 6 months Net 3.5 fixed the library errors.  Net 3.0 combined the VB library, c#, c++ into a single library.  Previously each language had a separate library.  So I suspect your original project was with c# Version 6 which used a different library than Net 3.0.  The libraries are similar but changes were made when the libraries were combined.